# How to prove or disprove that the series are Fourier transformation for some function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fourier-transform

Let's say, there is a function $\Sigma^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\cos 2k x}{\sqrt{2k \ln 2k}}$, how do I prove or disprove that it is a Fourier transformation for some function?

Comment: By Fourier transform do you mean Fourier series?

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes, Fourier series.

Comment: Is your sum over $n$ or $k$?

Comment: @JamesArathoon over $k$

Comment: What is exactly your question, you want to know if some given function $f$ is equal to this Fourier series ?

Comment: If you know Parseval-Plancherel, you can see that it cannot be the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function... But what kind of "functions" do you allow? That series is certainly the Fourier series of a "generalized function" (distribution), lying in a (periodic) Sobolev space $H^{-1}$, for example.